# Initialization of 2 datepickers very slow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the datepicker of [Angular-UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

I have a template that initializes 2 datepickers.

However, I noticed that it takes more than 100 ms on a desktop to initialize both.
It is worse than that using a two-years old mobile device.
I have the following declaration (2 times so):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="schedule.start" datepicker-popup date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"/>
```

However, when I remove the `datepickerPopup` directive, it takes less than 100ms.

Is there a way a trick to increase performance of `datepickerPopup` directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a pull request [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/pull/3666) that wraps the date picker popup in an ng-if that should fix that. The performance hit comes from the DOM rendering all the calendar elements.

Comment: I was having an issue with the year and month picker closing the popup, did you notice that as well? I posted a suggested change in the pull request comments.

Comment: Oh yeah indeed ! :( it closes it when I click I try to increment the year for instance for instance.

Comment: Just implemented your fix (preventClick), and now it works :) Thanks for pointing me out that :)!

Comment: Has this been released in 0.13.0 yet?  I have a few date pickers on my page and they are slowing down everything unacceptably (confirmed by Batarang's watches timer)